# Data load before all test case and Destroy after all test case

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

I am using `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` to run my Integration test case.
Now I am loading the data's to In memory HSQL for each junit test case in `@Before` method and Destroy it in `@After` method in Junit Test class.
 I need to have  data load should happen only once for all test case reside inside test folder . Also should be destroyed after completion of all test case.
I am using Maven for build,JDK8,Spring 4.2.5 and HSQL in memory.

Kindly help me to achieve this logic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible using [JUnit - Suite Test](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_suite_test.htm)

Create your Test Suite including all the necessary test classes. Configure your setup and teardown methods here

```
package com.test;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({Test1.class, Test2.class})
public class TestSuite {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
         // Set up database
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {
        // Cleanup codes
    }

}
```

And create your test classes normally

package com.test;

```
import org.junit.Test;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:context.xml" })
public class Test1 {
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("test1");
    }

}
```

Comment: I am using @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) .But your solution is with @RunWith(Suite.class) .Clarify me .

Comment: @user3669712 Add your @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) annotation in your test classes Updated my code.

Comment: @DO we need any test runner to run the testcase ? or we need to run Testsuite or Test1