# Instantiating huge data and sharing them with all tests before @BeforeAll

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, testing, junit5

What is the correct way to initialize some relatively big data, and share them (read only, so thread safe) across all JUnit5 tests?

I've looked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43464841/data-load-before-all-test-case-and-destroy-after-all-test-case) and others that are similar, but I always seem to have 1 or 2 more levels of assembly/instantiation than they deal with.

My testing setup is this:

1. I have a custom Repository data structure that needs to be initialized just once, read from multiple sources and assembled (about 100 - 200 mb) and then shared to all the tests.
2. Each test class instantiates an Engine in @BeforeAll, that needs the repository above and then goes on and executes the tests in series, calling engine.reset() between tests. Each test has it's own unique setup. Engine is semi-heavy, and impossible to have one for each test.
3. @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS) is used so we get only one instance per testing class, (and one engine per class).
4. Multithreading/Parallel testing is used, each test class is done in parallel, and methods within it are done in sequence. This means:

```
    systemProperty("junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled", true)
    systemProperty("junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default", "same_thread")
    systemProperty("junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default", "concurrent")

    systemProperty("junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.strategy","dynamic")
    systemProperty("junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.dynamic.factor",1) // could be 2!
```

Since there is nothing before @BeforeAll, I had to improvise:
I ended up declaring the repository on the top level of a kotlin test class file, outside of the class and initialize it like this: (large irrelevant chunks are omitted for clarity)

TestSetAlpha.kt:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*

val database:Repository = Repository().also{
    it.setupData(Config(...))
    it.someOtherInit() 
    blah blah
}


@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class `Engine Test Set ALPHA` {
    var eng = Engine()

    @BeforeAll
    fun initAll() {
        // configure Engine
        println("Configuring Engine ALPHA")
        eng.setDatabase(database)
        eng.configure {
            ....
            ....
        }

    }

    @BeforeEach
    fun init() {
        // reset the engine
        eng.reset()
    }

    @Test
    fun `A simple test`() {
        eng.add(...)
        eng.add(...)
        eng.execute()
        // interrogate resulting state
        assert(eng.property == ...)
        ...
    }
```

On subsequent test class files, I can reuse the same database Repository, and it only realy initializes once on a project level (verified!). There are no changes and no mutability on the repository after it loads, and that is guaranteed by it's API. This means that on an 16 thread CPU, I can reuse the database and roughly run 16 test classes in parallel.

I'm not sure on the loading and instantiating semantics of that global val. With a lot of data, JUnit5 is waiting for the also closure to complete before continuing with any tests, probably because it can't proceed with the classes on the files? I've never gotten an error, but feel this will probably break with a future update or on another platform because it's not clean and looks like a hack.

I would like to specify and have a guarantee that the repository is instantiated and shared properly across all classes & files and then have the threads start. How do you go about doing that though? There isn't some kind of top level, global @BeforeBeforeAll, although it would be exactly what I require. Any feedback and refactoring is welcomed. I can't run the tests without parallelism of course.

Answer (score 0):

Far simpler than I thought it would be!

On top scope or on another file, use a singleton object!

```
object DatabaseProvider {
    val database: Repository by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.SYNCHRONIZED) {
        val r=Repository()
        r.setupData(Config(...))
        // Load and add everything into the database 
        return@lazy r
    }
}
```

and then in each test class, you plug in the database as part of initialization:

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class `Engine Test Set ALPHA`{
    var eng = Engine()

    @BeforeAll
    fun initAll() {
        // configure Engine
        eng.setupRepo(DatabaseProvider.database)
        eng.configure= ....
        println("Configuration of Engine 1 DONE!")

    }
```

Note the lazy init mode set to synchronized.

The @BeforeAll methods will fire up before the database repository is loaded, but it will block on each test class until the initialization oof the repository is done, and then continue.